# Quantum group associated to a reductive group

Tags: rt.representation-theory, qa.quantum-algebra, quantum-groups, reductive-groups

In most of the classical references about quantum groups, these objects are defined as a one-parameter deformation of the universal enveloping algebra. However, I have read in several papers that it is possible to associate a quantum group to every reductive algebraic group G. I guess it has something to do with the fact that the Lie algebra of G is reductive, hence we can construct a quantum group using its semi simple part, but I haven’t found the details of this construction anywhere. Could someone provide any reference ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It is well-known and relatively straightforward for connected groups. You can quantise from the root datum, see, for instance, https://arxiv.org/abs/0807.2824

I do not think it is true as stated because the reductive group is not necessarily connected. I personally do not know how to quantise a reductive group with a non-trivial component group.